# Populate Dropdown with One2many field

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I have a model in which i create records, what I want to accomplish is from this records i have want display them in another module in a drop down. in the model I have added the One2many field that makes the relation with the main model but is not showing in the dropdown the records.

```
#original model where record are created
class Team(models.Model):
    _name = 'rw.team'
    
    number = fields.Integer(default= lambda self: _(1), readonly=True)
    name = fields.Char(string='Name', required=True, size=20)
    description = fields.Char(string='Description', required=True, size=40)

    project_id = fields.Many2one('project.project', string='Project')
    sale_order_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order', string='Sales Order', default="_get_default_so_id")
    
    team_id_lines = fields.One2many('project.task', 'team_id', string="team id lines")

    def _get_default_so_id(self):
      return self.env.context.get('sale_order_id')
    
    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
      if(vals.get('number', _(1)) == _(1)):
        last_number = self.env['rw.team'].search([('sale_order_id','=', vals.get('sale_order_id') )],order='number desc',limit=1)
        vals['number'] = last_number.number + 1

      result = super(Team, self).create(vals)
      return result
```

Model where i have the dropdown and want to get what is created from above model

```
class ProjectTask(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'project.task'

    team_id = fields.Many2one('rw.team', string="Team")
```

#Maybe a relation issue

Comment: It's strange, the many2one in `project.task` should show you data from `rw.team`. What happening when you click on many2one in view `project.task`?

Comment: when you click it it just does nothing so in the view, really strange!